# divide integer to multi by polynomial ring in BFV homomorphic algorithm

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

The BFV algorithm is one type of fully homomorphic encryption algorithms.

How can I encode an integer to polynomial ring by using batch encoder based on $R_t := {Z_t[X] \over ⟨(X^n)+1⟩}$? The plaintext space $(R \bmod t)$ is $R_t := {R \over t \cdot R}$ for some integers $t$ and encryption of the element $m(X) \in R_t$.

I need this for example to decompose or encoding 141 to polynomials.

Comment: Your formatting was all over the place, without clear sentences, capitalization or formulas. Please check if the formulas are now displayed correctly. Note that having a badly formatted question + a request for a quick answer is usually considered bad form here on [se]. We're in no obligation to you.